# Detecting whether a server is loaded

Tags: linux, process, search

I have to start some performance test on a Rhel 6 box, but before starting the test, i have to make sure there are no other java processes running.

The manual way of doing it would be to use `"ps -ef | grep java"`

But, since this test is going to be automated, i need a way to programmatically detect it and kill all of them.

Is there some way of doing it?

Comment: If you happen to search for processes, which you don't want to kill, just use `ps -C java` instead of `grep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about...?

```
pkill java
```

`pkill(1)` (also `killall(1)` on Linux) works like `kill(1)`, but sends the signal to all the processes with the specified name(s), not PIDs. There are other ways of matching processes too — check the man page!

In fact, specifically because this is Java we're talking about, I'd do the following to automate things properly:

```
pgrep java >/dev/null && (pkill java; sleep 5)
pgrep java >/dev/null && (pkill -9 java; sleep 5)
if pgrep java >/dev/null; then
    echo "Whoops, java processes still running. Bailing out."
    exit 1
fi
```

This will check if any java processes are running, send the, the `SIGTERM` signal and wait 5 seconds. If there are still processes running, it sends the `SIGKILL` signal and waits another 5 seconds. If there are *still* processes running, it stops executing the script returning an exit code of 1.

**Update:** changed answer to use `pgrep(1)` and `pkill(1)` instead of `pidof(1)` and `killall(1)`.

Comment: Caveat emptor! `killall` on Linux is special. `killall` on many other Unices sends a signal to **all** processes, not all processes matching a particular pattern.

Comment: It is CentOS we are talking about here. But any way `pkill` should do the job as well - and is propably secure on any Unix that sports that command (even OpenBSD does).

Comment: Indeed! (I just like to play it safe and mention this for other people reading the answer, people who might not know this). And I learned something new today. :) `pkill(1)` is also available on Solaris, so it's obviously the better way to do this.

Comment: In fact, I think I'll modify my answer to use `pkill`. That should make it compatible with most Unices.

Comment: php
-----
system("pkill java"); this line not working . i dono wat may be the problem. Can u help me. thanks

Answer (score 6):

It should be very simple with pkill:

```
pkill java
```

Answer (score 0):

First, write output of `ps -ef | grep java` to a file named "filename"
then create a Python file:

```
import os

f = open('filename',r')`
for i in f:
    a = i.split()
    b= "kill "
    b=b+str(a[1])
    os.system(b)
```

Run it with `python pythonfilename.py` and your Java programs will be terminated.

Comment: You may just use `ps -C java` instead of grepping the output of `ps`, but this solution is so overly complicated ...

Comment: @user unknown: I just followed his procedure. sorry I usually do this using python .I was not aware of pkill